# Calendar using ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have developing an app where I have made calendar using ListView just like a picture in this post.
I have been able to construct the ListView but I am facing some problem with month headers and days in month Can anybody help me in this regard

My getView method is

```
public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup p) {
    if (DateHelper.isHeaderEnabled(pos,cal)) {
        View rowView = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.calendar_list_row_month_header, null);
        final TextView headerTextView = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.month_header_textView);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");

        System.out.println(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        cal.setTime(current);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + pos / 30));
        current = cal.getTime();
        headerTextView.setText(sdf.format(current));
        return rowView;
    } else {
        View rowView = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.calendar_list_row, null);
        TextView dayTextView = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.weekDaytextView);
        TextView weekDay = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        dayTextView.setText("" + pos % 30);
        weekDay.setText(DateHelper.getDayName(pos));
        daysPos = daysPos + 1;
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

[image]

Regards
Altaf

Answer (score 0):

Have your listadapter accept a List Object>.
Then for month headers pass Strings.

In you getView() method of you adapter check which class the current object is.

If the class is your date, use standard layout, if your class is a String, use a header layout.

Comment: yeah but this listview is infinite and I have set all those things dynamically

Comment: I have posted the getView method